# Pinging server from VPN tunnel showing `Request timeout for icmp_seq`

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, openvpn, ping

I am successfully connected to a VPN tunnel to a router. I am trying to ping a server on this LAN with `ping 192.168.1.113`. This is returning:

```
PING 192.168.1.113 (192.168.1.113): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
--- 192.168.1.113 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

This server has `openVPN` service switched on. Therefore all outgoing requests are being made with `tun0` interface. This is the `tcpdump` during the pinging test:

```
12:29:21.027220 eth0  In  ifindex 2 e8:48:b8:e1:57:1a ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 104: 10.8.0.6 > 192.168.1.113: ICMP echo request, id 45097, seq 32, length 64
12:29:21.027357 tun0  Out ifindex 1063 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 104: 192.168.1.113 > 10.8.0.6: ICMP echo reply, id 45097, seq 32, length 64
12:29:22.004265 eth0  In  ifindex 2 e8:48:b8:e1:57:1a ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 104: 10.8.0.6 > 192.168.1.113: ICMP echo request, id 45097, seq 33, length 64
12:29:22.004411 tun0  Out ifindex 1063 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 104: 192.168.1.113 > 10.8.0.6: ICMP echo reply, id 45097, seq 33, length 64
```

`10.8.0.6` is the ip of the machine pinging via the VPN tunnel.
**Why is the connection not being received back.**

### Update

**switching off** the `openVPN` service on the server routes the packets correctly.

**is there something I need to add to the routing table in order to be able to connect to the server remotely when the server has an `openVPN` client services running?**